# Wpallimport check duplicate by title

Tags: xml, wordpress, woocommerce, feed, wpallimport

i have a affiliate product feed that contains alot of duplicate products. The SKU is different but its the same image, title and discription. Im using WPallimport.

Does anyone have a code that check's the database for duplicate title?

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar code snippet in the docs (see below). You need to modify it to check the title instead of a custom field.

Also note the additional check for the import ID - you'll need to update it as well (or remove it).

Original snippet: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/code-snippets/#only-create-a-post-if-an-existing-post-doesnt-have-the-same-custom-field-value

```
function create_only_if_unique_custom_field( $continue_import, $data, $import_id )
{
    // Only run for import ID 1.
    if ($import_id == 1) {

        // The custom field to check.
        $key_to_look_up = "my_custom_field";

        // The value to check where 'num' is the element name.
        $value_to_look_up = $data['num'];

        // Prepare the WP_Query arguments
        $args = array (

            // Set the post type being imported.
            'post_type'  => array( 'post' ),

            // Check our custom field for our value.
            'meta_query' => array(array(
            'key'        => $key_to_look_up,
            'value'      => $value_to_look_up,
            )),
        );

        // Run the query and do not create post if custom
        // field value is duplicated.
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    return !($query->have_posts());

    } else {

        // Take no action if a different import ID is running.
       return $continue_import;

    }
}

add_filter('wp_all_import_is_post_to_create', 'create_only_if_unique_custom_field', 10, 3);
```